# Copy and paste a .numbers file using R

Tags: r, file, copy, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy and paste a .numbers file (Apple's spreadsheet file) using this code in R:

```
file.copy("/Users/me/mypath/my_numbers_file", "/Users/me/mypath/my_numbers_file_COPY")
```

This has the desired effect of copying `my_numbers_file` and making `my_numbers_file_COPY`. However, `my_numbers_file_COPY` is an invalid file format that cannot be opened.

Any yet if I manually (with the mouse), copy `my_numbers_file` and make `my_numbers_file_COPY`, everything works fine.

Any suggestions why `file.copy` is making an invalid file format?

Comment: did you try adding the extension in your line of code?

Comment: Yes tried adding `.numbers` and surprisingly that didn't work either

Comment: `file.copy("/Users/bob/test/Untitled.numbers", "/Users/bob/test/Untitled_COPY.numbers")` worked fine for me. R 3.1.2, Yosemite, Numbers 3.5.2

Comment: Yes I'm on R 3.1.2 and Numbers 3.5.2. I can create `my_numbers_file_COPY` but cannot open it. Can you open it?

Comment: What happens if you use other copy methods like Finder Drag, or Terminal command `cp file1 file2` ?  For that matter, what does `GetInfo` on your copy tell you, and what happens if you open it with TextWrangler or other raw editor?

Comment: Using `file.copy` creates `my_numbers_file_COPY` that is 0 bytes therefore file has no contents, which is presumably why `my_numbers_file_COPY` cannot be opened. Why does `file.copy` create `my_numbers_file_COPY` that is 0 bytes and how can I get `file.copy` to make a file that a straight copy of `my_numbers_file`